Can't understand how text generator works when passing a shifted vector to the model during training
I'm really struggling understanding how a text generator can output the next word (token) given a text sequence. Since I'm trying to understand how transformers in such cases work, I'd be very happy, if you can help me to understand the "logic" behind it.
All the code posted here is taken from the jupyter notebook which comes with the book: Building Transformer Models with PyTorch 2.0. Going to their code in their repository here, there is a model declaration:
vocab_size = tokenizer.vocab_size
embedding_dim = 512
nhead = 8
num_layers = 6
num_classes = 2

# Create the model
model = TextClassifier(vocab_size, embedding_dim, nhead, num_layers,  num_classes).to(device)
criterion = nn.BCELoss().to(device)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

and the main loop definition:
num_epochs = 1
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    i=0
    for batch_data, batch_attention_mask, batch_labels in train_dataloader:
      
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Convert attention_mask to boolean tensor
        batch_attention_mask = (batch_attention_mask==0).to(device)

        outputs = model(batch_data.to(device), key_padding_mask=batch_attention_mask)
        loss = criterion(outputs, batch_labels.to(device))
        if i%100==0:
          print ("epoch ", epoch, "batch ", i, "loss ", loss)

        loss.backward()
        torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 0.5)
        optimizer.step()
        i=i+1

    print(f"Epoch: {epoch + 1}, Loss: {loss.item()}")

My problem is to understand how can the input_ids, the attention_mask and the labels interact with themselves for training the model.
Let's take a single batch of data from the train_dataloader (I took 1 batch to simplify as much as I could):
input_ids = [  101, 10047,  2125,  1012,  2070,  2028,  6045,  2232,  2275,  2017, 2006, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,     0,     0,  0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,    0,     0]
attention_mask = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
label = [10047,  2125,  1012,  2070,  2028,  6045,  2232,  2275,  2017,  2006,  102,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,   0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,   0,     0]

The input_ids is the original sentence, which has been tokenized and padded to reach a predefined length: Ok.
The attention_mask is the masking passed to the model during training. Now the first question here:

Why has the masking vector all 1s where a token is different then 0s? What is the purpose of this form of masking? I would expect masking the last word in the sentence (we want to train a text generator), so the last word should be masked. Or am I wrong here?
Then, we have the label. So the second question here:
The label vector is basically the same input_ids vector but shifted to the left. So let's take an output model which predicts the token after the token 6045 (index 6). In the original sentence (input_ids) the "right" token is 2232 (index 7). But in the label vector the token at index 7 is 2275. So there should be a mismatch wenn calculating the loss. And this mismatch has its origin in the shifting of the label vector and not for other reasons.
So it should converge at all.

It is clear, that I'm overlooking something very fundamental and important. I would thank you 10000, if you can point me in the right direction. Tkx
